# How can I print(or dump) a Parcel in native code, use logcat?

Tags: android, c++

We know that android has a class Parcel both in c++ and java, now I need to use logcat to monitor a parcel object in native code like this:

```
Parcel p;
p.writeInt32(...);
p.writeInt32(...);
...
// need to log parcel data here
LOGD(...);
```

How can I do that? I found Parcel has a member function print(TextOutput& to, uint32_t flags), but I don't know the usage... Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Parcel has a marshall() method that returns a byte array of the contents of the Parcel.